# Attribute not accessible via Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :roles
    has_many :networks, :through => :roles
end

class Network < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :roles
    has_many :network, :through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord:Base
    attr_accesible :user_id, :network_id, :position

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :network
end
```

The default for role is "member"

In the console I can type:

```
> @role = Role.find(1)
> @role.position
=> "member"
```

But in my Rspec tests, I use FactoryGirl to create a user, network, and role. And I have the test `@role.should respond_to(:position)` I have also tried just assigning it `@role.position = "admin"`. And no matter what, I get an error like:

```
Failure/Error: @role.should respond_to(:position)
  expected [#<Role id:1, user_id: 1, position: "member", created_at...updated_at...>] to respond to :position
```

Am I missing something very basic?

EDIT:

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name               "Example User"
    sequence(:email)   {|n| "email#{n}@program.com"}
  end

  factory :network do
    sequence(:name)      {|n| "Example Network #{n}"}
    location              "Anywhere, USA"
    description           "Lorem Ipsum"
  end

  factory :role do
    association :user
    association :network
    position              "member"
  end

end
```

network_controller_spec

```
...
before(:each) do
  @user = test_sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @network = FactoryGirl.create(:network)
  @role = FactoryGirl.create(:role, :user_id => @user.id, :network_id = @network.id)
  #I have also tried without using (_id) I have tried not setting the position in the factories as well.
end

it "should respond to position" do
  get :show, :id => @network
  # This may not be the best or even correct way to find this. But there should only be one, and this method works in the console.
  @role = Role.where(:user_id => @user.id, :network_id => @network.id)
  @role.should respond_to(:position)
end
```

Comment: Would be useful to see your full spec. For example, how you are defining `@role` in rspec?

Comment: It looks like @role is an array of Roles, rather than just one Role. would you add the code that sets @role?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott is probably right. He should have written it as an answer, so it can be marked as correct.

Comment: I very well may not be getting to that role correctly. There should ever only be one role between a network and a user, and in this spec I know it only returns one role, so if there is a more correct way to get that, please let me know. And Jesse, if your answer is right and you show me how to do it correctly, please submit an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesse is correct in his comment, hopefully he will come back and write it as an answer, in the meantime, the code should be:

```
@role = Role.where(:user_id => @user.id, :network_id => @network.id).first
```

or

```
@role = Role.find_by_user_id_and_network_id(@user.id, @network.id)
```

As an aside, it seems a little odd to be testing the role class in the network controller spec (unless this is just an exploratory test to work out why things aren't working as expected).

Comment: Actually, I really wasn't testing the role class, I was testing whether or not the destroy button appeared based on whether the user had an appropriate role, but since I couldn't get that to work,n so I decided just to test if respond to `:position`. Once it gets working I will use it for an appropriate test. Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the etiquette if Jesse doesn't post his answer? Do I select yours in the meantime? Do I never accept anything until he posts?

Comment: Give him a couple more days I guess?